# I do not know to append an attribute name enclosed in square brackets

Tags: html, css

I have no idea how to use this.  I have tried it using different ways, but nothing worked.

```
abbr[title] { border-bottom: 4px dotted green }
```

Comment: This is valid css that will style all <abbr> elements accordingly, provided they have a title attribute specified.  Is this what you were aiming for?  Please can you provide your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is documentation on how to accomplish appending and attribute name: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

And here is a demo on using those attribute selectors: http://jsfiddle.net/id_0t/q0g0jako/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hello-example">
    <a href="http://example.com">English:</a>
    <span lang="en-us en-gb en-au en-nz">Hello World!</span>
</div>
<div class="hello-example">
    <a href="#portuguese">Portuguese:</a>
    <span lang="pt">Olá Mundo!</span>
</div>
<div class="hello-example">
    <a href="http://example.cn">Chinese (Simplified):</a>
    <span lang="zh-CN">世界您好！</span>
</div>
<div class="hello-example">
    <a href="http://example.cn">Chinese (Traditional):</a>
    <span lang="zh-TW">世界您好！</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* All spans with a "lang" attribute are bold */
span[lang] {font-weight:bold;}

/* All spans in Portuguese are green */
span[lang="pt"] {color:green;}

/* All spans in US English are blue  */
span[lang~="en-us"] {color: blue;}

/* Any span in Chinese is red, matches simplified (zh-CN) or traditional (zh-TW) */
span[lang|="zh"] {color: red;}

/* All internal links have a gold background */
a[href^="#"] {background-color:gold}

/* All links to urls ending in ".cn" are red */
a[href$=".cn"] {color: red;}

/* All links to with "example" in the url have a grey background */
a[href*="example"] {background-color: #CCCCCC;}
```